# How to apply styling to n out of 5 <li>'s based on a dynamic numeric value?

Tags: jquery

I have a ratings display of 5 `<li>`'s:

```
___ ___ ___ ___ ___
|_| |_| |_| |_| |_|
```

I have a dynamic variable with a numeric value eg:

```
var rating = 3;
```

How can I apply styling to the number of `<li>`'s that equal the rating value?

So for example, if `var rating = 3`, then three boxes would have a grey background.

The list can be created on the fly.

I've made an example of a long way to go about it, but there must be a shorter way to accomplish it:

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/m6MV2/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="ratings_ul"></ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
var rating = 3;
var ratings_ul = $("ul.ratings_ul");
var li_rating = "<li class=\"styled_li\"></li>";
for ( i = 0; i < rating; i++ ) {
    ratings_ul.prepend(li_rating);
};
var li_rating_ns = "<li class=\"not_styled_li\"></li>";
var list_length = $("li.styled_li").length;
var to_add = 5 - list_length;
for ( i = 0; i < to_add; i++ ) {
    ratings_ul.append(li_rating_ns);
};
```

**CSS**

```
ul.ratings_ul {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

li.styled_li {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background: #ccc;
display:inline-block;
border:1px solid #000;
}

li.not_styled_li {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background: #eee;
display:inline-block;
border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the style after you've appended all li's

```
var rating = 3;
var ratings_ul = $("ul.ratings_ul");
var to_add = 5;
for ( i = 0; i < to_add; i++ ) {
    ratings_ul.append('<li></li>');
};
$('.ratings_ul li:lt('+rating+')').addClass('styled_li');
```

also give the li default style in the css

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m6MV2/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var rating = 3;
var ratings_ul = $("ul.ratings_ul");
$('.ratings_ul').html(new Array(6).join('<li></li>'))
$('.ratings_ul li').slice(0, rating).addClass('styled')
```

then

```
ul.ratings_ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
ul.ratings_ul li.styled {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #ccc;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
ul.ratings_ul li {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #eee;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/953FC/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var total_rating    =   5;
    var rating          =   3;


    for (var i = 1; i <= total_rating; i++) 
    {

        if(i < rating)
        {
            $('.ratings_ul').append("<li class='not_styled_li'></li>");
        }
        else
        {
            $('.ratings_ul').append("<li class='styled_li'></li>");
        }
    };

});
```